# HTML5 canvas rendering- path clipping

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

In My case i have performed path clipping and then draw a image in clipped region. But it does not working.

here my code.`

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var offset = 50;
  /*
   * save() allows us to save the canvas context before
   * defining the clipping region so that we can return
   * to the default state later on
   */
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.clip();
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-  vader.jpg';
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now image render without clipping.

Please share your valuable key to do this.

Comment: What do you mean, not clipping? Put a print maybe, I'm seeing image only in context circle, do you want for the image to be processed?

Comment: You have a typo in your image URL (2 un-needed spaces), but otherwise your code does work to clip darth vader into a circle.